# nuxt.js small project wont deploy on netlify

Tags: nuxt.js, netlify

[image]

> I've deleted the cache in the node_modules folder and reinstalled it again but didn't work please can someone help?

Comment: Can you please share more of the screenshot? Also, does it work locally? Can you please share your `nuxt.config.js` file?

Comment: @kissu Yes sir, it works great locally. If you need it, here is the project https://github.com/marouane44/Hassan_said_second_try.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've followed those steps to have a [successfully hosted app](https://practical-mahavira-883937.netlify.app/):

- `git clone` your project
- run `npm i` to install all the packages
- `npm run generate`
- opened my file explorer, drag and drop'ed the `dist` directly on https://app.netlify.com/drop
- it works great with Node `14.18.1` and NPM `8.1.3`

Comment: thank you sir for your help I followed all your steps netlify said the site has deployed but nothing happened I don't know  https://i.ibb.co/sKVXV4m/ddde.png    https://i.ibb.co/WHrZDC5/dp2.png

Comment: Please edit your question and please provide more visuals. Also, what have you written in `/settings/deploys`? This is probably the part where something is missing. @lakouismarouane

Comment: I didn't do anything on "settings" sir ; The drop option is my first time deploying, I usually deploy via GitHub, so I'm not sure how it works ,thanks sir

Comment: @lakouismarouane when you setup your Netlify github repo at first, you do need to provide some settings. Basically this video: https://youtu.be/gaC-l9MAE9Q

Comment: Sir, I have tried every single step and, the same error keeps showing                                                  https://i.ibb.co/TkvgZzQ/ggggg.png

Comment: @lakouismarouane you do have a node version of 16 in your screen. You should probably set the env variable `NODE_VERSION` to `14`. More info here: https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/manage-dependencies/#node-js-and-javascript

Comment: You're a lifesaver, thanks so much, works like a charm